# maxSpan function implementation

Tags: java

The original question is as follows:

> Consider the leftmost and righmost appearances of some value in an array. We'll say that the "span" is the number of elements between the two inclusive. A single value has a span of 1. Returns the largest span found in the given array. (Efficiency is not a priority.)
>
> maxSpan([1, 2, 1, 1, 3]) → 4 
> maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 1, 4]) → 6 
> maxSpan([1, 4, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4]) → 6

Here is my implementation of the maxSpan function.

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
  Map<Integer, List<Integer>> spans = new HashMap<>();
  for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!spans.containsKey(nums[i])) {
      List<Integer> position = new ArrayList<>();
      position.add(i);
      spans.put(nums[i], position);
    } else {
      List<Integer> position = spans.get(nums[i]);
      position.add(i);
    }
  }
  int globalMaxSpan = 0; // empty set has maxSpan = 0
  for (List<Integer> value : spans.values()) { //iterating over values only
      int localMaxSpan = 0;
      if (value.size() > 1) {
        localMaxSpan = value.get(value.size() - 1) - value.get(0) + 1;
      } else localMaxSpan = 1;
      if (localMaxSpan > globalMaxSpan)
        globalMaxSpan = localMaxSpan;
  }
  return globalMaxSpan;
}
```

Here is another implementation of the same algorithm I found on GitHub implemented by others.

```
public int maxSpan(int[] nums) {
    int max = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int j = nums.length - 1;
        while(nums[i] != nums[j])
            j--; 
        int span = j - i + 1;                                 
        if(span > max)
            max = span;
    }                                             
    return max;
}
```

Although my implementation is O(n) runtime but it is more complicated than the below implementation. Please give comments to my code in different aspects. Thanks.

Comment: Please include the specification that you are implementing. I.e. what does maxSpan mean?

Answer (score 2):

Your choice of data structures is unnecessarily heavy. You're interested only in the first and last index of a number, so store only those in a lightweight data structure of two integers (an array):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    final int num = nums[i];
    int[] span = spans.get(num);
    if (span == null) {
        span = new int[] { i, i };
        spans.put(num, span);
    } else {
        span[1] = i;
    }
}
```

Java comes with built in functions for selecting larger or smaller number from two, so use them instead of if-statements or ternary operations. It makes code easier to read.

```
// Empty set has maxSpan = 0
int maxSpan = 0;
for (int[] span: spans.values()) {
    maxSpan = Math.max(maxSpan, span[1] - span[0] + 1);
}
return maxSpan;
```

Avoid end-of-line comments. They make the code messy and are a pain in the ass to maintain. Avoid unnecessary comments that describe *what* code does. The reader can already see that the code iterates over values. Instead document *why* the code does what it does.

Use variable names that describe what the variable is used for. `Value` does not give any new information to the reader about what it contains.

`Position` as a name for a list is deceptive. It's singular form suggests that it contains one value when it instead contains all positions of a certain number.

Edit: You don't actually even need to store the last occurrence of a number. Just store the first one and calculate the maxSpan as you traverse the array the first time.

```
int maxSpan = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    final int num = nums[i];
    Integer firstIndex = firstIndexes.get(num);
    if (firstIndex == null) {
        firstIndex = i;
        firstIndexes.put(num, firstIndex);
    }
    maxSpan = Math.max(maxSpan, i - firstIndex + 1);
}
return maxSpan;
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, you are right we don't need an extra loop for calculating maxSpan.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor modifications can be applied to your code to improve readibility, your first part of code is this:

> ```
> Map<Integer, List<Integer>> spans = new HashMap<>();
> for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
>   if (!spans.containsKey(nums[i])) {
>   List<Integer> position = new ArrayList<>();
>      position.add(i);
>      spans.put(nums[i], position);
>   } else {
>      List<Integer> position = spans.get(nums[i]);
>      position.add(i);
>     }
> }
> ```

You can use a ternary operator and aggregate operations executed in both branchs of `if else` like below:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> spans = new HashMap<>();
final int n = nums.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    boolean condition = spans.containsKey(nums[i]);
    List<Integer> position = condition ? spans.get(nums[i]) : new ArrayList<>();
    position.add(i);
    spans.put(nums[i], position);
}
```

Same suggestions for the second part of your code:

> ```
> int globalMaxSpan = 0; // empty set has maxSpan = 0
> for (List<Integer> value : spans.values()) { //iterating over values only
>     int localMaxSpan = 0;
>     if (value.size() > 1) {
>        localMaxSpan = value.get(value.size() - 1) - value.get(0) + 1;
>     } else localMaxSpan = 1;
>     if (localMaxSpan > globalMaxSpan)
>       globalMaxSpan = localMaxSpan;
> }
> return globalMaxSpan;
> ```

You can write a more concise code like this below using again a ternary operator because you already know every list has at least one element:

```
int globalMaxSpan = 0;

for (List<Integer> value : spans.values()) {
    final int size = value.size();
    int localMaxSpan = size > 1 ? value.get(size - 1) - value.get(0) + 1 : 1;
    globalMaxSpan = Math.max(globalMaxSpan,localMaxSpan);
}

return globalMaxSpan;
```

It is possible to write a more complex version of this part of code to avoid calls `max` operations (I made it) when lists contains exactly one value, but the version is not concise like this and so I won't post it.